# Created standalone app with CRNA, why APK sizes differ?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I tried two ways to compose a standalone Android app from CRNA project:

1. Use the Expo "exp build" command ([this guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html))
2. Eject and build an APK manually ([this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html))

Both ways work well and yield the working APKs, but the first one is of 26MB size while the second one is only 7MB!
Why "exp build" generates so large APK?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer:

If you need to keep your app size extremely lean, Expo may not be the best choice. The size for an Expo app on iOS is approximately 25mb, and Android is about 20mb. This is because Expo includes a bunch of APIs regardless of whether or not you are using them — this lets you push over the air updates to use new APIs, but comes at the cost of binary size. We will make this customizable in the future, so you can trim down the size of your binaries.

Source is [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo.html#if-you-need-to-keep-your-app-size-extremely-lean-expo-may-not-be-the-best-choice-the-size-for-an-expo-app-on-ios-is-approximately-25mb-and-android-is-about-20mb-this-is-because-expo-includes-a-bunch-of-apis-regardless-of-whether-or-not-you-are-using-them--this-lets-you-push-over-the-air-updates-to-use-new-apis-but-comes-at-the-cost-of-binary-size-we-will-make-this-customizable-in-the-future-so-you-can-trim-down-the-size-of-your-binaries)